# How to add 2 modifs to the same file in OCMOD file for opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart2.3, ocmod

I want to add a small snipet of script above a block of script and another one under the same block in the same file. (I can't do a replace because the block is also modified by another extension).

If I had the same file twice I get the message "Modification requires a unique ID code" when installing the extension (Please note that if I remove one of the file section it uploads fine so the issue is not actually with the code ID)
Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Spare Parts</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Olivier</author>
    <code>spare_parts</code>
    <link></link>

    <file path="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation error="log">
                <search index="0"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");]]></search>
                <add position="before"><![CDATA[
                                    //spare parts extension

                                    if ( $product_id !=671 )
                                        {//only update the options if this product is not the spare parts

                    ]]>
                </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
  <file path="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation error="log">
                <search index="1"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");]></search>
                <add position="before"><![CDATA[
                                    }//end except spare parts

                    ]]>
                </add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

I have tried with using the  twice in the same  and even use the search and add twice under the one operation but I am getting the same error:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Spare Parts</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Olivier</author>
    <code>spare_parts</code>
    <link></link>

    <file path="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation error="log">
            <search index="0"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
                                //spare parts extension

                                if ( $product_id !=671 )
                                    {//only update the options if this product is not the spare parts

                ]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="log">
            <search index="1"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
                                }//end except spare parts

                ]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Spare Parts</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Olivier</author>
    <code>spare_parts</code>
    <link></link>

    <file path="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation error="log">
            <search index="0"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
                                //spare parts extension

                                if ( $product_id !=671 )
                                    {//only update the options if this product is not the spare parts

                ]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="log">
            <search index="0"><![CDATA[$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
                                }//end except spare parts

                ]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

I have changed `index="1"` to `index="0"`
When you use for the second add `index="1"` you close your condition in the next function (`public function copyProduct($product_id) {`). I assume you need this exception just for `public function editProduct($product_id, $data) {` If you need it for the second function you must your conditions add separately.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same error with the second index="1", also, the second search does not search the same string as the first and since there are 2 occurences of the same  search string if it was working it is likely the snipet would be added in the wrong place

Comment: you must use second index="0" like in my example

Comment: it still gives the error Modification requires a unique ID code! (with both index="0") as soon as I add the second <operation> tag, if I remove it, the error is gone

Comment: You should uninstall first your old one. Or if you are not able to uninstall, you can find it in your DB via phpmyadmin. oc_modiffication table and remove there your extension.

Comment: I have it uninstalled, the issue is not with duplication as the error indicate, the same file using <operation> just once uploads just fine

Comment: I did not see in your file any issues... You can try vqmod if you using OC2.3. Just do not forget xml file little bit different for VQMOD